# awk read strings with spaces into array

Tags: awk

I have a file named CFILES with below content:

```
#Start
Microsoft
Facebook
Google is Ok
#End
```

I am trying to get these values into an array :

```
readarray -t arr< <(awk '/Start/,/End/' CFILES)
```

However, "Google is Ok" is not being read as single item. How can I fix this?

Comment: try `echo "${arr[3]}"`

Comment: Include in your question the currently missing code that when executed shows that  "Google is Ok" is not being read as single item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reate array by `readarray` which you did and get values from a for loop in case you want to traverse through all values of an array.

Creating array:

```
readarray -t  arr< <(awk '/Start/,/End/' Input_file)
```

Traversing through an array:

```
for ((i=1; i<${#arr[@]}; i++))
do
   echo "${arr[i]}"
done
Microsoft
Facebook
Google is Ok
#End
```